# Change directory with -d in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to give the option to the users to run the script in a different directory. However when the script changes the directory, the `mkdir` does not work.
I change the directory like this:

```
case $1 in
 "-d")
   PWD=$2;;
   *)
     ;;
esac
```

but when I run the script, it runs in the directory that it exists. it does not change the directory.

here is the complete code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#File sorter
set -e    # Abort in case of error
START=$(date +"%T")
SAVEIFS=$IFS
case $1 in
    "-d")
      PWD=$2;;
    *)
      ;;
esac
echo "trigger took place in $PWD"
for i in *; do
  echo "processing \"$i\" ..."
  case $i in
    *.zip)
      [ -d archive ] || mkdir archive
      mkdir "archive/${i%.*}"
      unzip -d "archive/${i%.*}" "./$i"
      echo -e "\"$i\" extracted in $PWD/archive/${i%.*}" >> report.txt;;
    *.*)
      mkdir -p "${i##*.}"
      mv -- "$i" "${i##*.}/"
      echo -e "\"$i\" moved to $PWD/${i##*.}" >> report.txt;;
    *)
      tmp=$(TMPDIR=. mktemp -d)
      mv -- "$i" "$tmp/"
      mv -- "$tmp" "$i";;
  esac
done
echo "Done in $SECONDS seconds!"
END=$(date +"%T")
echo "Start time: $START" >> report.txt
echo "End time: $END" >> report.txt
```

Comment: A comment not on the question: why don't you use `cd` to change directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not surprised that changing `PWD` doesn't do anything.

Simply do a `cd "$2"`

> but when I run the script, it runs in the directory that it exists.

It runs in the working directory of the shell you executed it.. If you're in the directory of the script, then yes, it will execute there.

Answer (score 1):

The `PATH` variable is reserved for finding programs that the shell will use.  It is a list of directories, separated by colons (`:`) which is searched in order until the program is found.  From the manpage of [`bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

> PATH
>
> The search path for commands. It is a colon-separated list of directories in which the shell looks for commands (see COMMAND EXECUTION below). A zero-length (null) directory name in the value of PATH indicates the current directory. A null directory name may appear as two adjacent colons, or as an initial or trailing colon. The default path is system-dependent, and is set by the administrator who installs bash. A common value is ''/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/ucb:/bin:/usr/bin''.

If you change that variable, it changes how the shell finds programs, like `mkdir`.

I suggest changing the variable to `path` or `dir` (case matters in Linux/UNIX).

Comment: Where does he use the `PATH` var? I cannot see it.

Comment: @enzotib I edited the question, first it was PATH then I tried it with PWD

Comment: PWD is a variable that is set by the shell.  To change the directory, use `cd _directory_`.  For example, `cd /var/log`.  If returns a non-zero return value if the shell is not able to change the current directory.  The `cd` is a builtin command in the shell, not a program.

Comment: Also, you're not doing anything about the fact that if $1 is -d, you're not removing it and $2 from the list of files to operate on.  Take a look at the 'shift' operator in the bash documentation.